# Almost sure convergence: example

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> A factory wants to estimate the amount of incidents occurring during the
>   production of a product $A$. Incidents occur at times $T_1, T_2, \dots$ where $T_i = X_1 + X_2 + \dots + X_i$
>   and $(X_i)_i$ are i.i.d. and positive. Let
>   $$M(t)=\max{\{n:T_n\le t\}}$$
>   denote the number of incidents that occurred up to time $t$. Assume $\Bbb E(X_1) < \infty$ and prove that $M(t)\rightarrow\infty$ as $t\to\infty$ a.s.

If I understood the question correctly I have to show that $$\mathbb{P}\left(\lim_{t\to\infty}M(t)=\infty\right)=1$$
I am given that $E[X_1]<\infty$, so I probably have to use the Markov-inequality at some point. I however don't see how, could anyone give me a hint?

Comment: Have a look at two events $\{M(t) \geq k\}$ and $\{T_1 \leq t, ... , T_k \leq t\}$.

Comment: You can try to say $\mathbb{P}(\lim_{t\to\infty}M(t)=\infty)=0$ and get to a contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it that way.
Let's negate the probability you want to prove and see if it leads us to a contradiction.

$$\mathbb{P}(\lim_{t\to\infty}M(t)=\infty)=0$$

Since $M(t)$ is an increasing sequence of integer, this implies :

$$\mathbb{P}(\exists L \in \mathbb{N},\lim_{t\to\infty}M(t)=L)=1$$

This is the same as :

$$\mathbb{P}(\exists L,N \in \mathbb{N}, \forall n \geq N, M(n)=L)=1 \Rightarrow \mathbb{P}(\exists n \in \mathbb{N}, T_n =\infty )=1$$
This tell us that : $\mathbb{P}(\exists n \in \mathbb{N}, X_n=\infty)=1$, which is impossible because $E[X_1]<\infty \Rightarrow \mathbb{P}(X_1 < \infty)=1$

Answer (score 2):

The limit $\lim_{t\to\infty} M(t)$, call it $M(\infty)$, exists because $t\mapsto M(t)$ is non-decreasing. To show that $\Bbb P(M(\infty)<\infty)=0$, it suffices to show that $\Bbb P(M(\infty)=k)=0$ for each positive integer $k$. But $\{M(\infty)=k\}\subset \{T_{k+1}=\infty\}$. Now find $\Bbb P(T_{k+1}=\infty)$.

Comment: To find $\Bbb P(T_{k+1}=+\infty)$ he can use indeed Markov's inequality, correct?

Comment: Indeed, he can.